# Is it possible for processes to share the L2/L3 cache?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, caching, x86

In a typical x86 multicore system, the L2 cache is shared among the cores. I was wondering If two processes use shared memory, do they also share the L2 cache? Or is it that only threads can share cache but not processes?

Comment: CPU cache is just a front for physical memory.  If two processes read from the same physical memory address, then the second access will be resolved from cache.

Comment: using a shared library does not imply shared memory

Comment: So what happens when two processes are using shared memory. Lets say, P1 reads the first byte of the shared memory, which is brought into cache, would P2 get that value from the cache if it also reads the first byte of that shared memory?

Comment: I post as a comment, but it actually _is_ an answer: Yes. And the good news: they do already! Nothing to be configured. Otherwise, your system would become slow like hell.

Comment: @NG. OK, assume I'm talking about shared memory then.

Comment: You should first read how CPUs, MMU and virtual vs. physical memory works. There's a lot of resources, just search for it!

Comment: L2 is private, L3 can be shared

Comment: +jdl - In some processors L2 is also shared.

Comment: +Oliver Charlesworth - But I read that some processors use CPU cache as front for the virtual memory rather than physical memory.

Comment: @jdl: Even L1 can be shared actually. IIRC CPUs stopped using locical L1 cache with 68040/80486 (not sure about Intel, though). Or did they change back? I haven't cared for quite some time. Flushing ~64KiB of cache on each task-switch seems quite bad to me

Comment: Ln cache naming doesn't mean anything. It's a relative ordering from the core outward. L2 on Blue Gene/Q is similar to L3 on x86, except Blue Gene/Q doesn't have a equivalent L2s, so they call the LLC an L2.